# Vue How to trigger vuejs-datepicker after it has been closed

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs-datepicker

In my `vuejs`-application I have added the [vuejs-datepicker](https://github.com/charliekassel/vuejs-datepicker) which I trigger by clicking a button. When I've chosen a date, the datepicker is closed but when I try to open the datepicker again, nothing happens and I don't know why?! It seems that it only opens once...

here is a snippet of my code:

```
<span @click="openDatePicker">open date picker</span>

<datepicker v-model="selected_date" @selected="isSelected" @closed="closeDatePicker" ref="datepicker"></datepicker>
```

then in my methods:

```
openDatePicker() {
   this.$refs.datepicker.showCalendar();
},
closeDatePicker(){
  I tried to to:
  this.$refs.datepicker.close();
}
```

any suggestions?

Comment: Looking at the github repo, it look like the last commits were 2 years ago.  If it's no longer being maintained, you may want to search for an alternative.

Comment: I agree with @Tim seems the lib is really outdated. I let you here a link with some alternatives maybe you find a more recent updated one 
[Calendar Alterantives](https://madewithvuejs.com/blog/best-vue-js-datepickers)